# Convert cURL to Salesforce APEX rest api

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest, curl

Hoping someone could help with this little problem I am having, I have a cURL that works just fine, but what I need is an Salesforce APEX / Rest API / HttpRequest instead. Here is my cURL:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer f43e0234e30ec45467065b6c1543a0d3f2" -d "{
  \"username\": \"string\",
  \"password\": \"string\"
}" "https://thingspace.verizon.com/api/m2m/v1/session/login"
```

Comment: Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67867

Comment: Hi Jerry, I linked a question I answered previously that may very well answer your question. Please take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be to look at the [documentation on HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm).

Most everything should map fairly intuitively from cURL.

For example...

- `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, etc... are Http methods, so use `setMethod(String method)`
- you'd pass `'https://thingspace.verizon.com...'` into `setEndpoint(String endpoint)`
- each individual header is set by using `setHeader(String key, String value)`, e.g. `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <token string here>')`
- POST data is sent in the body of the request, so `setBody(String)` is what you'd use

The actual request is sent by using the `send()` method of the `Http` class ([documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_http.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_http))

About the only other gotcha that I can think of is that you can't examine the network request (because it is sent from one of Salesforce's servers), so it's a very good idea to store the `HttpResponse` result you get from `Http.send(HttpRequest request)` in a separate variable, and have logic to inspect the status code via `HttpResponse.getStatus()` and `HttpResponse.getStatusCode()`.

If you don't check the response code/message, you won't have any way of determining if your callout worked, or what went wrong (if it didn't work).

Comment: HTTP auth = new HTTP();
String payload = 'username: me' + 'password: pass';
HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
r.setEndpoint('https://thingspace.verizon.com/api/m2m/v1/session/login');
r.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueOf(payload.length()));
r.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxx);
r.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
r.setBody(payload);
r.setMethod('POST'); HTTPResponse authr=new HttpResponse();
authr = auth.send(r);
authr.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
DEBUG 400 {"errorCode":"REQUEST_FAILED.UnexpectedError","errorMessage":"Bad Request"}